# Typeface.js not rendering in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, typeface.js

just wodering if anyone has experience with Typeface.js ( http://typeface.neocracy.org ) and fixing issues of the font not being rendered in Internet Explorer ( 6, 7 and 8 ).

The font renders in Firefox and Safari fine, hover nothing is displayed in the Explorers. The font is not installed locally so I know that the script is working.

I am using the typical usage of

```
<div class="typeface-js" style="font-family: Optimer">
    text to change
  </div>
```

I have checked the authors forums and using the font file with all of the characters, I just don't know whats up.

Any advice appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

are you testing your HTML Page locally? internet explorer has some restriction on executing javascript locally, if so try to upload the page to your server, or use WAMP as a local server

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. Its on a server, it worked fine locally.